# Why Paw's dynamic values do not count current environment?

Tags: paw-app

Let's say I want to create environment's domain for users with different roles: **Regular** role and **Admin** role. I need user's auth token for every request, so I set header value for **/auth/signin/** as a dynamic value:

```
Respone Parsed Body/auth/signin/ > token
```

But when I switch user environment from one role to another, dynamic value for *token* doesn't count new environment. And every role uses the same *token* for authentication.

What is the best way to work with different roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question. Currently "Response Parsed Body" dynamic values are using the latest response, regardless of the current selected environment. *(We're going to make it possible in a future release)*

What I suggest for now (as a workaround) is to create two different auth/login requests, one per environment/role, and a new environment variable that would point to the right request. I tried to explain this through this screencast: http://cl.ly/1X0B2H2o1o1S

Comment: Oh, it looks like pretty smart workaround. Thank you for quick reply, sharing video and for pointing me out that environment variables could contain dynamic values. I didn't use this feature before.